# Drawing a very simple component in KiCad without the model

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I am designing a PCB in KiCad that includes the [328ST160 and 328SR160 transducer pair](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3109324.pdf). I have been unable to find a PCB symbol for the two.

The physical component I have is just two pins, like so:

[image]

I was wondering whether I could just draw a resistor on the PCB schematic editor, like so, and then edit the size of the resistor pins, or whether there's something in KiCad I missed that would make this approach invalid.

[image]

Comment: You mean you couldn't find a PCB symbol?  You can draw one as would make sense or just use any other 2 pin symbol that looks right.  The symbol is just to help you read the circuit.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, a PCB symbol. That's why I'm using the resistor since it should count as a 2-pin symbol, right?

Comment: What you have shown is a schematic symbol.  You will also need a PCB footprint.  The schematic symbol and PCB footprint are two separate items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is a good idea to get used to making your own symbols, for generic things like transducers that usually isn't necessary because KiCad comes with a lot of included symbols:

[image]

In this case, using the stock "Speaker_Ultrasound" as the symbol would probably make it more clear than something you drew yourself.

Comment: ...with the caveat that one still needs to be sure that the PCB symbol is appropriate.  So, it may be a better suggestion to say: "it's OK to start with an existing SCH symbol (if it's available), and then add an appropriately designed PCB footprint as per the part's datasheet."

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Not in KiCAD! The way it works is that symbols are distinct front PCB footprints, so there is no corresponding PCB footprint to go with that symbol.  This is by design, it forces you to make sure that you pick a correct footprint to go with the generic symbols.

Comment: My goal was to point out that one needs to construct the necessary footprint based on the datasheet of the part (and not assume that a 'found' footprint would be at all appropriate).  50% of our job is to check the other 50%.

Comment: @user1850479 isn't that true for any EDA piece of software?

Comment: @VladimirCravero no it isn't there are some EDAs around where you have a plethora of resistor "symbols" each with a footprint attached (e.g. 0805, 0402 and 0402_metric and stuff like that). I think Eagle and Target do it that way. All approaches have their pros and cons...

Comment: Well I count myself lucky then. Granted, I use EDA only for schematic design, I never maintained a library or done any serious layout work, so I am not fully capable of evaluating advantages and disadvantages of the approaches.

Answer (score 6):

You can make your own schematic symbols and PCB footprints in KiCad (or most other electronic CAD programs).

If you do any amount of PCB design, you *will* have to make your own symbols and footprints, so you may as well start now.

The schematic symbol and footprint editors will allow you to create new symbols from scratch or to edit existing symbols to suit your needs.

Using a resistor symbol to represent transducer would be confusing...

Comment: This is a great component to use as a first custom footprint to make.  Just remember to oversize the through-holes slightly and "position relative to" will help you avoid placement errors.